# Leakage rate Calculation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, diffusion

I have to calculate leak rate for helium/air from an enclosure which is made of fabric. This is similar to helium balloons. There are small holes in the fabric. How should i proceed ?

Comment: related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21291/calculate-fluid-pressure-loss-due-to-hole-leakage and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44784/how-to-determine-whether-a-large-container-is-air-tight